# Make two exe interacting

Tags: c#, singleton, exe, interaction

I created a singleton class as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EnergyManager
{
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton istanza;
    public static Services Service;
    private Singleton(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Services.BehaviourType ProgramBehavior = new Services.BehaviourType();
            ProgramBehavior = Services.BehaviourType.NationalProviderConsole;
            Service = Services.Instance(ProgramBehavior);
            Application.Run(Service.SelectedFormTabs);
        }
        else
        {
            Service.ModifyTerminal(Convert.ToInt32(args[0]), Convert.ToInt32(args[1]), Convert.ToInt32(args[2]));
        }

    }
    public static Singleton Instance(string[] args)
    {

        if (istanza == null)
        {
            istanza = new Singleton(args);
        }
        return istanza;

    }

}
```

}

What I would like to do is that when args is not null, it receive the current status of the class Services and I continue to work on that state.

This class singleton is called by the Program.cs

```
     static void Main(string[] args=null) 
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Singleton Sing = Singleton.Instance(args);
        }
```

that is the entry point. Suppone the exe is called Test.exe.

The problem is that, the working situation is this:
I first run Test.exe with no command line argument, than a the instance Service is created in the class  singleton. Then I run again Test.exe with some command line arguments. So, when Singleton.Instance(args) is called in Program.cs, in the class Singleton it enter in the else condition of the if, BUT the Service is not instanciated. This is because the two exe I runned do not see the state of each other. How can I modify the code in such a manner that when I run Test.exe for the second time, it gets the state of the Test.exe I runned the first time?

Comment: The only way to persist data/state between execution is to save it to a file.

Comment: Interprocess communications is a rather large topic. Are you only interested in having multiple active instances of the code interact, or persisting the state when no instances are running?

Answer (score 0):

You can use memory mapped files. It is like writing the state to a file but uses virtual memory and can be accessed by multiple processes. See [Memory Mapped Files (.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx). You can also look at this [Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx) to give you guidelines on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Memory Mapped Files like already suggested or WCF: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/a-simple-example-of-wcf-service/